# Calculating coupling metrics in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am analyzing and comparing several java projects and I would like to get the total number of dependencies between files at the package level(a rough measure of coupling at package level) and also the total number of files within a package. Is there any way to get these metrics automatically into an excel file. I know I can do it manually but as I have to do it for multiple projects would like to find an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the web service API. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API.
More specifically, for your use case, the Resources web service. See http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280.

Note that there is also some examples of Excel files calling the web service API that you can adapt to your needs. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extracting+Data+with+MS+Excel.